# T-SQL UNION Performance issue

Tags: sql-server, performance, union, common-table-expression

I have two kinds of query with did the same job here

Query 1 :

```
SELECT MP.MemberName FROM MemberProfile MP 
LEFT JOIN Order O ON MP.MemberID = O.MemberID
WHERE O.TotalAmount >= 100

UNION

SELECT MP.MemberName FROM MemberProfile MP
LEFT JOIN Order O ON MP.MemberID = O.MemberID
WHERE O.Quantity >= 10
```

Query 2 :

```
;WITH cte AS (
     SELECT MP.MemberName, O.Quantity, O.TotalAmount FROM MemberProfile MP 
     LEFT JOIN Order O ON MP.MemberID = O.MemberID
)
SELECT MemberName FROM cte WHERE TotalAmount >= 100

UNION

SELECT MemberName FROM cte WHERE Quantity >= 10
```

In real environment will be more complicated query, these just a simple version for other to read

Question:

1. Is it better to use CTE instead of using JOIN every single time, base on performance and also redundancy?
2. Is there a better way to do this UNION or even UNION ALL query other than these way.

Comment: Check your query plan. My guess is that the CTE will be folded in to give the same query plan both times, but to be sure check it.

Comment: Query plan result gave very minor of costs different for these 2 type of queries, even time consume are barely noticeable amount of different. Might left it or switch it around for the real environment for testing. and tune it further if got performance issue. thanks anyway..

Comment: CTE acts like macro.CTE is good for readability but its performance is not better as compared to temporary tables better use temporary table if possible. If you are joining multiple tables with millions of rows of records in each, CTE will perform significantly worse than temporary tables.

Comment: Don't just check the execution plan - use STATISTICS IO and STATISTICS Time to see the exact values because as @DashangG.Makwana mentions - the performance of a CTE can be quite awful if not careful with large/semi-large result sets.

Comment: Using UNION ALL instead of UNION will improve performance unless you need to eliminate duplicate rows in the result (like your sample).  Also, you could use an `INNER JOIN` in your sample queries because the `WHERE` clause predicate references the outer table and will never return `NULL` values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there will any big difference between CTE and JOIN in your case. SQL Server optimization will convert it to something complete different and these two queries will produce probably the same result. You can try to add indexes on TotalAmount and Quantity if selectivity is high.

Comment: good point about using indexes, ill try it for further tuning.. thanks anywhere